# Unable to filter/group the menu items based on the category of the pages in the Menu using wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus

In my WordPress website I have the navigation requirement bit different from the provided menu functionality.In this top navigation the Tab would be the name of Category and all the page URLs under this tab would be the pages having this category associated.
For example if I have an category named **SPORTS** and pages hockey, cricket, badminton & Tennis are associated with this category **SPORTS**. I need these pages in the navigation like below -

**SPORTS** 
   -Hockey 
   -Cricket 
   -Badminton 
 
   -Tennis

I want to produce HTML markup as below -

```
<ul> 
<li>
<a href="#">**SPORTS**</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href=" Hockey.html"> Hockey </a></li>
<li><a href=" Cricket.html"> Cricket</a></li>
<li><a href="cratHertz.html"> Badminton </a></li> 
<li><a href=" Tennis.html"> Tennis </a></li> 
</ul>
---------
</li> 
-------
</ul>
```

I am using `wp_nav_menu( $args )` . Could somebody help me in filtering/grouping the menu items/pages based on category.

**EDIT** - 
We do not require any page for SPORTS  in CMS so not having any page link also on that.I can say that its just a Category Name of the pages which are coming under this tab as menu items( Hockey,Cricket etc). I am thinking an approach to print the Category names just above the Menu items of this category. I am able to print these menu items with the help of wp_nav_menu( $args ) perfectly but unable to print the category name of all the menu items(pages) just above them.

**IN A NUTSHELL** - I WANT TO GROUP PAGES IN THE wp_nav_menu( $args ) BASED ON THEIR ASSOCIATED CATEGORY INSIDE A LOOP RUNNING FOR ALL EACH CATEGORY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a custom class extending [`Walker_Nav_Menu`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker_Nav_Menu), which is the default walker for `wp_nav_menu()`.

Implementation would be as such:

```
$args = [ 'menu_id' => 'main_menu', 'walker' => new SE287172_Walker_Nav_Menu() );
wp_nav_menu( $args )
```

You would also want to add a custom class to the menu item. For this example, we'll go with `vinayak-custom-class`, as you'll see in the walker's code below.

You would need to define your Walker, and override the `start_el()` method. This would allow you to add additional HTML Markup depending on a number of things. You have the Menu Item object at hand, so you could base the custom submenu on a class, the title, the ID, etc.

I'd recommend a class, as hard-coding to a title may screw you over if the "SPORTS" menu item ever changes to be "Our Sports" or something similar and your sub-menu disappears.

You would place this in your `functions.php` file or ideally, another file in a `/includes/my-nav-menu-walker.php` file (or similar) where you keep your code organized.

```
class SE287172_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

        // Let the main class do it's thing first. Then shove your submenu in.
        parent::start_el( $output, $item, $depth, $args, $id );

        // Now do your class check
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        if ( in_array( 'vinayak-custom-class', $classes ) {
            // Do your Submenu HTML Output
            $output .= 'My Sports Sub-menu goes here';
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, you can then do a `get_posts()` call within the class check to grab your pages in your Sports category, and loop through them, creating your `<li>` structure.

Comment: Hi Eric , thanks for your reply but it does not meet my requirement. I have updated the question above ( EDIT section)  could you please refer it and help me

Comment: So you want to generate a menu by not using anything in a WP Menu area? This isn't directly achievable.

What you're really trying to do is create a loop of your Categories, and then a sub-loop of the Pages attached and listing them out, is this correct?

Comment: @Vinayak you would want to look at how to create a walker and use it. You could still extend `Walker_Nav_Menu`, but you would need to recreate the funcitonality inside of the `wp_nav_menu` function and then use your walker to handle the output.